# psycopg2 - Laravel Local Env

Tags: php, python, laravel, xampp, psycopg2

I am trying to get the psycopg2 module for python running in my Laravel application. It is working online on Heroku (I installed it there), but I am wondering about how I can get it running locally.

In Laravel I use:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
```

Locally it throws this Error:

```
import psycopg2
ImportError: No module named psycopg2
```

On heroku, the code works properly, so it is just about the environment.
Does anyone know how to fix that?

PS: I use XAMPP locally

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Care to explain the purpose of this black magic? You obviously do not have psycopg2 installed http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi

Answer (score -1):

I'm running debian jessie and managed to get python 2.7 installed twice.  When I specify the directory (/usr/bin/python or /usr/local/bin/python) I can make the "No module" error appear and disappear.  Since I haven't seen this explanation before, I thought I'd share my experience.  Seems strange that ALL the attempts at installation acted on the version in /usr/local/bin, while the PATH selects the version at /usr/bin.  I think I will try removing the one at /usr/bin.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: It is not clear how this resolves the problem in question.